# Nuxt 3 / Vutify loading js (script) resources multiple time

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

we have a application which have issue that when we run project it is sending script request more than 2500 to 3000 when we load the application and due to that we are having memeory error sometime on production.

Need a help on that. thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH3Ll.png)

We checked every settings in nuxt.config.ts, every api queries and all.

Comment: Looks like a dev build, prod builds usually do not bother with vue files. Are you sure you are building for production before deployment?